# Nhibernate 3.2 start to finish walk-through that uses built in conForm

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm looking for a tutorial on Nhibernate 3.2 that uses the built-in code configuration that NHibernate provides.  I'm not interested in using Fluent NHibernate, nor the old-style XML mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html and related articles from the same blog are the closest thing you'll find.

Fabio is the NHibernate lead and original author of the NH mapping-by-code.

Answer (score 0):

The best example I've seen of the 3.2 loquacious mappings was in this post.

http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-envers-quick-introduction

It has a sample project which clearly shows most of the 3.2's mapping features.

I tried following Fabio's series of posts and found them a little confusing.  I suspect since he wrote the 3.2 mappings he's got intimate knowledge that he isn't conveying.